# linear layout: the button text tends to the right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Recently I changed my RelativeLayout to LinearLayout and since the text of my button is placed always on the right side. And I would like to see it centered.

[image]

It doesn't worth to change the `android:ems`, because different values pass for different languages.

This is how my button looks like. As `android:layout_with` and `android:layout_height` stay `wrap_content` value, which does not help.

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/buttonLog"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/login"          
      android:textAllCaps="false"  
      android:textAlignment="center"        
      android:textColor="@color/aquamarin" 
      android:textSize="19sp"
 />
```

Preview picture looks nice.

[image]

And this is the full version of my login screeen:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etLogin"
            android:hint="@string/usernamehint"
            .../>

        <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            ...
            />

        <Button
             android:id="@+id/buttonLog"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="@string/login"          
             android:textAllCaps="false"  
             android:textAlignment="center"        
             android:textColor="@color/aquamarin" 
             android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_right"
         />

    />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this :

```
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

This work when you have this:

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

### so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/usernamehint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_right"
            android:background="@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="login"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/EscosAquamarin"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107932/discussion-between-amit-vaghela-and-user2957954).

Comment: did you check answer@user2957954

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to the button's attributes should do the trick. it tells the parent how to layout itself.

Answer (score 0):

in your code `<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLog"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/aquamarin"
            android:background="@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_right"
         />`
change `android:layout_gravity="right"` to `android:layout_gravity="centre"`

Comment: this moves button to the center

Comment: is that not what you wanted?

Comment: NO! I want the button on the right side. I want the button of normal size and the text in the center

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with this attribute which functioned ok in RelativeLayout and makes the button small and uncentered in LinearLayout

```
android:background="@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
```

I replaced it with the method inside my jaca Activity class:

```
 buttonLog.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BackgroundToolbarGrey));
```